# mysql error ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed mysql server and I logged in with `mysql -u root -p` and it was working good. But then I moved my data directories to another location, now when i use `mysql -u root -p` it shows me error like  `mysql error ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`  but if I try to login with `sudo mysql -u root -p` this command allows me to connect. Because of this i event can't able to connect with MySql Workbench. 
Please Help me. As I am new to linux i don't have much knowledge about it.